# After booting I have many letters missing in Ubuntu, especially the file manager, the folders and login page

Tags: boot, grub2, nautilus

After booting today, the letters are mostly not appearing.

This affects among others the file manager, taskline and related menus, and the login-page. Folders are lacking their names or the names are reduced to something like "_ AC  X", with most letters removed.

Edit: Now the Files menu does not open anymore.

Edit2: I tried to access Files via

```
nautilus --browser 

** Message: 17:40:02.438: Connecting to org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I can browse in Firefox or use the console.
I cannot browse the folder system from the browser, for example I did not manage to insert a screenshot to this post. Also in other apps I am not able to browse the folder system.

I update and upgrade regularly with sudo apt-get update/upgrade
Maybe the last update was not good?

Versions:
Linux 6.5.7-060507-generic x86_64
Ubuntu 23.10

I tried boot-repair and was gives this link:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pvGKpXtFGf/

I have no linux experience and need clear advice.

Edit: Thanks. After saving my data in a backup, I could not boot anymore. Had to set up Ubuntu new. Problem  „solved“ :(

Comment: This looks like a font or graphical corruption issue. Please run memtest86 and badblocks. Also try nomodeset in /etc/default/grub to use safe mode graphics.

Comment: Thanks. After saving my data in a backup, I could not boot anymore. Had to set up Ubuntu new. :(